# Open Bootstrap 5 modal will shift the header and background to the right

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm using Angular 2 and Bootstrap 5 for front-end. When open a modal, the header and background shifts to the right, which cover the scrollbar.

After checking, I realized that the HTML code changed from

`<body class style>`

into

`<body class="modal-open" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 17px">`

After that, I tried to fix by adding the code both in CSS file and HTML tag:

```
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
```

But the only thing fixed is that the scrollbar was no longer covered, the header and background were still buggy. Also using class `p-xl-0` at the `body` tag didn't change anything at all. Are there any idea about this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You describe your header and background as “shifting,” but are they shifting or expanding? You did not include any of your code in your question (a code snippet is the best), so it’s difficult to provide a specific solution. Can you edit your question?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds `overflow: hidden` to the body when displaying a modal to prevent the user from scrolling the body’s content, and, if the modal content is larger than the window, the scrollbar will be shown and will scroll the modal ([or you can optionally have a scrollbar on the modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content)).

You describe your header and background as “shifting,” but you didn’t provide any information on your header and background. If the header or background is `position: fixed` and the width is 100%, the header or background will expand to fill the width without scrollbars.

Bootstrap prevents the body and navbar content expanding by adding a padding amount equal to the scrollbar (e.g. 17px for Firefox, 15px for Edge). If you do have some fixed position content, it will also need the extra padding added while the modal is being displayed.

You can have Bootstrap do this by adding the class `.is-fixed` to the element that’s shifting on you. Bootstrap will apply (and remove) padding to any elements that have the class `.fixed-top`, `.fixed-bottom`, `.is-fixed`, or `.sticky-top`. `.is-fixed` has no styles associated with it (reference the [scrollbar.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/42a055c7a8e611523c2d10650a465d75d0bb362b/js/src/util/scrollbar.js#L16) file). It’s just for Bootstrap’s JavaScript to find the element and apply padding when a modal is being displayed.

Below are two code snippets, the first does not have .is-fixed applied to the image, so the image will expand to fill the scrollbar space, and the second has .is-fixed applied to the image. The image in the second will not expand.

**Example where the image will expand:**

```css
.btn-modal {
  margin-top: 4.5rem;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 150vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-warning">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<section>
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog">

</section>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**Example where the image will *not* expand:**

```css
.btn-modal {
  margin-top: 4.5rem;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 150vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-warning">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<section>
  <img class="img-fluid is-fixed" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog">

</section>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The image is from https://loremflickr.com. Their images are all licensed under Creative Commons licenses and are sourced from Flickr. The title of the image and the owner are credited on each image.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds a Class to the `<body>` tag when the Modal is open called "modal-open" and also decorates it with in-line styling, the whole thing looks like this:

`<body class="modal-open" style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 17px;" >`

We can use this class to target the static in-line styles that are appended to the `<body>` tag

So, placing the following in your stylesheet *AFTER* Bootstrap:

```
body.modal-open{
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

This will override the padding-right shift when the modal opens inside the Body Tag.

**NOTE: A full browser cache reload may be required for the changes to be reflected in the DOM. (Ctrl + Shift + R).**